# Getting coordinates from image in Java Android

Tags: java, android, image, bufferedimage, pixel

I am using BufferedImage from Java in an Android project. In this project the user is allowed to select a small portion of an image.

For example: If you have an image of a park with a building. The user can make small selections of grass and the android program needs to save the coordinates of this selection.

I was wondering if there is functionality in BufferedImage that supports this: letting an user select small portions of the image (using touch screen) and getting coordinates from those locations in the image. If not, what else can I do?

Comment: you mean image is capture through camera....?

Comment: image can be captured through camera or just be contained in a file. bufferedImage deals with image files.

Comment: even you need to store location like ExifInterface to store latitude longitude but still you need ltd lngtd of portion from image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the pixel position (x, y) (i.e. cursor position) of the click in to *SQLite* database and you don't need to store all values around it. If you want to check a click which comes around this pixel (with a tolerance value), the following code will help you :

```
    int[] xyReceivedPixel = { 15, 20 };
    int[] xyOriginalPixel = { 30, 15 };
    int toleranceValue = 30;

    boolean status = (xyReceivedPixel[0] < xyOriginalPixel[0] + toleranceValue 
            || xyReceivedPixel[0] > xyOriginalPixel[0] - toleranceValue)
            && (xyReceivedPixel[1] < xyOriginalPixel[1] + toleranceValue 
                    || xyReceivedPixel[1] > xyOriginalPixel[1] - toleranceValue);

    System.out.println(status);
```

Here, `xyOriginalPixel` is the original pixel point which is stored in the database and the `xyReceivedPixel` is the pixel point that is got when another click was made or a pixel point that is to be compared with it. The `xyReceivedPixel` is checked whether it is near by `xyOriginalPixel` with the maximum difference of `toleranceValue`.